# Swift как поменять ширину и высоту картинки в коде?

Tags: swift, uikit

Как изменить ширину и высоту картинки в кнопке в коде(независимо от реального размера картинки)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно использовать стандартный `imageView` из `UIButton`, то изображение нужно добавлять только при помощи метода `setImage`, тогда при изменении размеров кнопки изменится и размер изображения

Пример:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(<# Some UIImage here #>, for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(button)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8)
])
```

Не рекомендую использовать одновременно `frame` и `NSLayoutConstraint`, лично по моему опыту `NSLayoutConstraint`, более надежный инструмент

Если такой способ не подходит, то можно добавить `UIImageView` через `button.addSubview(imageView)`